# How to specify 'root' in path in text file

Tags: unity, 12.10, launcher, root, paths

I'm following this tutorial located [here](http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/10/ubuntu-how-to-add-eclipse-to-unity.html) on how to create a launcher for eclipse in unity. Everything is going pretty well so far, I've managed to successfully create the launcher but when I click on it, my system complains that the path to the exec is wrong.

My exec for eclipse is located here:

> ~/opt/eclipse/eclipse

And if you look at the tutorial you have to create a file and set it's contents like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=./opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=true
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

In my case I have to provide the full location for the exec and there are a number of things that I tried that didn't work I set 'exec' to 'Exec=~/opt/eclipse/eclipse' , 'Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse' and 'Exec=root/opt/eclipse/eclipse' and none of these worked..

What should I set it to in order to fix the path so that my luancher works?

Update------------------

I tried to list those 2 directories and what i get is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every user, `~/` signifies its home folder. For every regular user, that would translate to `/home/username`, for example, `/home/dean`, but for the `root` user, to `/root`.

Since the executable is located in toot's home folder, the full path will be as follows:

```
/root/opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I changed it now but when I click the eclipse icon nothing happens.. strange?

Comment: Well, you can verify the executable is actually there, by running `ls /home/dean/opt/eclipse/eclipse`.

Comment: No such file or directory it says...hmmm

Comment: Is `dean` your user name? If not, substitute your existing user name instead.

Comment: yep that is indeed my username

Comment: Double check the spelling, and that `~/opt/eclipse/eclipse` path is correct. `~/opt/eclipse/eclipse` and `/home/dean/opt/eclipse/eclipse` are the relative and the absolute paths, but if the executable is not actually there, it's not going to work.

Comment: It seems that they're not the same directories though. Have a look at the screenshot in my updated post. btw thanks for being persistent, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Since you've changed to the `root` user in the terminal, the relative path (in other words `~/`) starts in `/root`, which is the home folder for the root user. So, in your particular case, the executable and everything else is probably located in `/root/opt/eclipse/`.

Comment: Ah you're right! So basically I just have to go set that variable in the file like so: Exec=/root/opt/eclipse/eclipse ?

Comment: Yep, that said, `/root` is hardly a proper place for eclipse or any other program. I'd move everything to /opt with `cp -r /root/opt/eclipse /opt`. The path will then be `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`.